# Length of a contract limited or not?

Tags: contract-law, india

Is there any limit to the length of a contract ? Can someone sign a 10000 page long contract that would basically take years to interpret with some repeating but relevant clauses .
Example : a contract has clause 1 refer to clause 89 which refers to clause 10000

Answer (score 4):

### There are many contracts that are well over 10,000 pages

For example:

- mining contracts - the environmental impact statement alone is likely to be of the order of 10,000 pages.
- privatised prisons - it takes a lot of pages to set out the expectations of the government on things like prisoner welfare
- defence contracts - aircraft carriers are complex pieces of machinery; 10,000 pages would barely scratch the surface

These do take years to interpret, but they are interpreted by teams of hundreds, sometimes thousands of lawyers and engineers, so while they take several person-years they may take less than one actual year. Of course, these sorts of contracts may spend years in the negotiation phase as well.

Comment: generally, ship contracts consist of hundreds of partial contracts, some of them as short as order forms for standardized parts plus the TOS of the supplier, others contain up to 50% technical specifications that define what exactly the contracted part needs to look and fulfill...